# How to show a specific div from an external site on one of my webpages

Tags: wordpress, html, embed

I have a Wordpress-managed site and I would like to embed a specific part of another website in one of my pages. I have identified the `div` of the part I'm interested in with Firebug. How can I get it to appear on one of my web pages? Simply using an `iframe` displays the whole page, but I'd rather have the specific `div` only.

The webpage I want to fetch the `div` from is [outfitpoints.com](http://outfitpoints.com/OutfitDetails/OutfitByID?outfitId=37514290234406964)
and the particular `div` is `div id="outfitdetails"` (the box of details seen on the page). It's this box I'd like to have appear on one of my pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of Outfitpoints, so I thought I'd answer with a few options.

Firstly, the data I use comes straight out of the Planetside2 API (census.soe.com), so you could write something that pulls some data yourself straight from the source.

However, yours is not the first request to provide this sort of data in a way people can imbed on their own site, so I will be looking into providing the data in that format in the very near future.

What sort of site are you looking to embed it in (enjin, guildlaunch, vbulletin etc.)? Just so I can test and make sure it works with it.

Also, feel free to give me a shout using the contact method on the site if you want to discuss it more.

Comment: oh thanks for the reply! Outfitpoints is a great site, i must say, good job with it. I wanted to make an outfit website, and i was going to use wordpress. So i was looking for a way to have some summary statistics of the outfit viewable on the site. A plugin, or something embedded from another site. With no experience in coding i havent got a clue how to ask the api for the info and make it into something visual like your tables.

Comment: @user2623403 I've just finished building this, you can add that table now by adding some simple HTML to your WP site, see here - http://blog.outfitpoints.com/2013/07/28/embeddable-stats/